# While loading subview from xib to UIScrollView getting error 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, subclass, xib

I am trying to load a custom UIView from xib

**customView.swift**

import UIKit

```
@IBDesignable class customView: UIView {

var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    xibSetup()
}


func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let nibName:String = "customView"
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView // **Getting error at this line**
    return view
}
}
```

**customView.xib**

File's Owner is the CustomView class.

**In StoryBoard**

I have a UIViewController (Scroll View Controller) with a UIView with the custom class: CustomView. The xib @IBDesignable propagates through and all is well.

Now the problem starts. I am trying to use the customView multiple times (just like cells in a tableView) in the ScrollViewController, just as I do with viewOne

**MyUIViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit


class MyUIViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let height = CGFloat(234.0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.bounds.size.width, height)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(height*3,self.view.bounds.size.width)
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

    var y = CGFloat(0.0)

    for i in 0..<2 {

        //Adding viewOne
        let viewOne = self.createViewOne(i)
        viewOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 200)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(viewOne)

        //Adding CustomView
        let customView = self.createCustomView(i)
        customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 200)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(customView)

        y += height
    }

}

func createViewOne(index: Int) -> UIView {
    let viewOne = UIView()

    if index == 0{
        viewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    if index == 1{
        viewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    return viewOne
}


func createCustomView(index: Int) -> UIView {

    let customViewDummy: customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! customView

    if index == 0{
        customViewDummy.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    if index == 1{
        customViewDummy.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    return customViewDummy
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I am trying to load a custom UIView from nib multiple times in ViewController.

I referred following link - [How to use custom nib view in ViewController multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551404/how-to-use-custom-nib-view-in-viewcontroller-multiple-times/28552258?noredirect=1#comment66497133_28552258)

I am using Xcode 7.3.1

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you In advance.

Comment: Instead of assuming everything is correct with `[0] as! UIView`, check whether the array has any content and, if it does, check whether `[0]` has the kind of object you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one more `view` within your `customView` and adding it as `subView`. Hence some mismatches. Try below code and make sure your `filesOnwer` is set to `customView`:

```
@IBDesignable class customView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    return myView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am getting the same error at line -         let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView